# Retrieving books from gutenbergr in Spanish

Tags: r, regex, text-mining

I need to download books in Spanish using the `gutenbergr` package. The problem is that seemingly in all Spanish texts, special characters (e.g., á, ñ) are encoded.

```
    > library(gutenbergr) 
    > Text<-gutenberg_download(36558)
    > Text[,2]
# A tibble: 638 x 1
   text                              
   <chr>                             
 1 [imagen]                          
 2 ""                                
 3 "Rat\xf3n P\xe9rez"               
 4 ""                                
 5 CUENTO INFANTIL                   
 6 ""                                
 7 Por el P. LUIS COLOMA. S. J..     
 8 "de la Real Academia Espa\xf1ola."
 9 ""                                
10 Dibujos de M. Pedrero.
# ... with 628 more rows
```

The thing is that the encoding is not 100% consistent. For example, above you can see that in "Ratón" the "ó" is encoded as \xf3, but if you go down in the text, you can find this:

```
Text[26:27,]
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  gutenberg_id text                                                               
         <int> <chr>                                                              
1        36558 "\xc1 SU ALTEZA REAL EL SERENISIMO SE\xd1OR PR\xcdNCIPE DE ASTURIA~
2        36558 "DE BORB\xd3N Y BATTENBERG."
```

.. where the "ó" in "Borbón" is now \xd3.

I tried replacing with `gsub`, but it didn't work:

```
Text$text<-gsub("\\\xf3", "ó", Text$text)
> Text[,2]
# A tibble: 638 x 1
   text                              
   <chr>                             
 1 [imagen]                          
 2 ""                                
 3 "Rat\xf3n P\xe9rez"               
 4 ""                                
 5 CUENTO INFANTIL                   
 6 ""                                
 7 Por el P. LUIS COLOMA. S. J..     
 8 "de la Real Academia Espa\xf1ola."
 9 ""                                
10 Dibujos de M. Pedrero.            
# ... with 628 more rows
```

Any ideas on how to replace the special characters with either the right one (e.g., á, ó) or the standards (e.g., a, o)?

Comment: Just convert the lines to the right encoding. `ntext <- sapply(Text, iconv, "latin1", "UTF-8")
`

Comment: `sapply(Text[,2], iconv, "latin1", "UTF-8")` also works, doesn't it?

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work. I finally went with 
`> Enconding(Text[,2]) <- 'latin1'`